# Linux drivers for laser printer Konica Minolta Magicolor 4750DN

Tags: linux, drivers, laser-printer

I would like to install the Konica Minolta Magicolor 4750DN in Linux (debian 64 bits, I know it's not really supported but that's not the issue right now) but all the manual says is "put the CD-ROM in and copy the drivers and PPD file". However I did not get the CD!

On their "fantastic" internet site there are only available drivers for Windows and Mac OSX.

I tried to extract the ppd file from the .dmg file for MacOSX 10.7 but, if the PPD file works, a compiled file (only mac compiled, MACH 4 architectures says the "file" command) does not (obviously "cannot execute binary file", since I'm trying to run a Mac file on Linux).

Is there anybody who has the same printer that could lend me the Linux drivers on the CD ROM ? Couldn't find them anywhere on the internet. Any way to execute a Mach (or BSD) binary file on Linux (I don't think is possible, although some "emulators" may exist).

Thank you very much. I bought this printer even because it was advertised as "Linux compatible", only to get this bad surprise. I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this printer, but this seems to work:

- Download the windows postscript driver (i used 1.0.2.0 for windows 7)
- unzip the file
- cd ./mc4750/english/Drivers/Win_x86/PS/english/
- apt-get install mscompress
- msexpand kobjpa__.pp_
- mv kobjpa__.pp kobjpa__.ppd

Comment: May I ask you where you found this information ? Or you just tested it with a similar printer ? To me the problem is not the PPD file (I got that from MacOS X 10.7 uncompressing the DMG file), but the cups filter (a binary program which I don't have). I don't think using the Windows printer driver will allow that to happen (though I'd get another ppd file).

Comment: You have installed cups (apt-get install cups)?
After reading the reference guide pdf from their webpage im sure that this "printer driver" is nothing else than the ppd file. 
I have installed many different postscript printers (mostly hp and some oki) and it would be strange if your printer needs any other software than cups and the ppd file.

Comment: I used the command: msexpand kobjpa__.pp_ (otherwise it complaints about an underscore). When I try to add the printer to cups (127.0.0.1:631) it says "Unable to copy interface script - No such file or directory". Furthermore the ppd file generated is unreadable (strange characters), whereas the file from MacOSX is readable. About the external binaries here is what the MacOS driver needs:

Comment: *% === Plugin Path OSX10.5 (OSX) ===================
*APDialogExtension: "/Library/Printers/KONICAMINOLTA/mc4750/PDEs/KONICA MINOLTA mc4750 Color.plugin"
*APPrinterIconPath: "/Library/Printers/KONICAMINOLTA/mc4750/Icons/KONICA MINOLTA mc4750.icns"
*cupsICCProfile CMYK../CMYK Profile: "/Library/Printers/KONICAMINOLTA/mc4750/Profiles/mc4750ps.icc"
*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 /Library/Printers/KONICAMINOLTA/mc4750/filter/pstomc4750PS"

Comment: Note: I do not possess any mac ! It's just that I though the driver was similar between mac and linux since they both use cups for printing. Am I missing something ?

Comment: and if I rename the file you said I should use to kobjpa_.pp, then expand it I get something that is readable, but I still get a missing star ("*") error which is a (non-standard) PPD file.

Comment: OK fixed it.It works (but only if I print monochrome). Otherwise it prints 10 pages instead of 1 duplex. This is the first time that to get to use the printer I would have to code its driver :( I can live without the duplex (in fact I only use it once in a year almost), but the color print is strange ...

Comment: Maybe use someting like pastebin.com, then it seems like the comment funktion doesn't allow any formating. I tested the ppd from the windows zip and i could load it into cups after i deleted the comments(?) in the lines 46 and 54. It was even possible to print a testpage with this ppd although I have an OKI postscript printer.

Comment: can't help you with the details of the konica-minolta because i have an oki here at home and oki/hp at the workplace.

Comment: I can print only in greyscale and that works good. If I try to print something which is colored (say a piece of text in libreoffice writer or evince pdf) I get 10 pages out of the printer instead of just one (and the text is wrong !). I commented the same lines. I suppose we have the same file then: [link](http://pastebin.com/aeQfFvzG). Even the test page gets out in 4 pieces of paper, none of which in color as it should. I used to get almost this result a while ago when I tried desperatly to use the 4690 (?) driver, which I deleted because it was trash.

Comment: OK thank you. At least now something works ...

Comment: Just to inform you that I contacted konica's support via web form and I got a reply in about 4 days (I waited for this for 1 year now, so I was not really in a hurry). You have to go to
http://www.konicaminolta.eu/business-solutions/support/download-center.html
, select "printers colour", your printer "MC4570DN" , Type of Driver: 'PPD', Operating system: "Linux". They've been very kind and now it works perfectly even in color (haven't tested the duplex yet). Thanks konica's support !

Answer (score 0):

The PPD is available here: http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/download/SearchResults.aspx?productid=1301

Direct link: http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/DownloadFile/Download.ashx?fileid=29469&productid=1301